# Why the type traits template __or_<_B1, _B2, _B3, _Bn...> needs _B3?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm reading some code in the std c++ type_traits header (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/type_traits)

```
 112   template<typename _B1, typename _B2, typename _B3, typename... _Bn>
 113     struct __or_<_B1, _B2, _B3, _Bn...>
 114     : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, __or_<_B2, _B3, _Bn...>>::type
 115     { };
```

And I don't understand why we need _B3, because I think B1, B2 and Bn is enough

```
 001   template<typename _B1, typename _B2, typename... _Bn>
 002     struct __or_<_B1, _B2, _Bn...>
 003     : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, __or_<_B2, _Bn...>>::type
 004     { };
```

What's the purpose of _B3 here in the STL _*or* template?

Comment: *Only* the implementer can give you an answer to why he wrote it this way.

Comment: At a guess, to ensure the template is instantiated for three or more arguments (not two or more).    However, this code uses reserved identifiers, consistent with it being implementation-specific - so talk to the implementer.

Comment: This might be done to make a clear distinction between specializations that have two and three or more parameters.

Comment: With your proposed solution, if `_Bn` was empty, this would lead to the instantiation of `__or_<_B2>`. Which may not make sense.

Comment: @DanielLangr I guess OP omitted a specialization that has two parameters. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01609_source.html).

Comment: `__or_` is an implementation detail. It only makes sense to discuss how it is implemented by considering where it is used and what for.

Comment: Did your alternative suggestion work?

Answer (score 4):

We are able to look at the source of gcc/libstdc++ and use their VCS to see when `__or_` was added. It was added with [123c516a](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=123c516a9ee069efe6783682ff0bfbf28ec94919), and looked like:

[(direct link)](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits;h=a4c76730f5b79dfda1de36038e6c2bd1b1183b39;hb=123c516a9ee069efe6783682ff0bfbf28ec94919#l62)

```cpp
  template<typename, typename, typename...>
    struct __or_;

  template<typename _B1, typename _B2>
    struct __or_<_B1, _B2>
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, _B2>::type
    { };

  template<typename _B1, typename _B2, typename _B3, typename... _Bn>
    struct __or_<_B1, _B2, _B3, _Bn...>
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, __or_<_B2, _B3, _Bn...>>::type
    { };
```

So originally `__or_` only accepted 2 or more arguments and could not be implemented without `_B3` (Since `_Bn` could be an empty parameter pack, and  `__or_<_B2, _Bn...>` would lead to `__or_<_B2>` being used).

Even after `__or_<> : false_type` and `__or_<T> : T` was added, it might still make sense to have the "extra" overload for exactly two arguments, as that's one less template for the compiler to expand. Either way, not much reason to remove it.